# Django Postgres error, field "is not of a character type"

Tags: django, django-models

This is one of those sanity-check questions. This should be incredibly obvious. Either something's up with the driver or I'm overlooking something obvious.

I have a Django model field. It's an integer field, non-null, with choices.

```
PROVENANCE_X = 0
PROVENANCE_Y = 1

PROVENANCE_CHOICES = [
    (PROVENANCE_X, "Provenance X"),
    (PROVENANCE_Y, "Provenance Y")
]
```

In the model:

```
provenance = models.IntegerField(choices=PROVENANCE_CHOICES, default=PROVENANCE_X)
```

Just to check, here's what Postgres says:

```
provenance     | integer                 | not null
```

When I save the model in the admin I get an error.

```
DatabaseError
column "provenance" is not of a character type
```

There's no custom admin stuff going on. The fault is entirely in Django code, but I can't tell where. I put a breakpoint in the `save` method just to check, immediately before calling super:

```
(Pdb) print self.provenance
0
```

So is some code, somewhere, trying to insert a character rather than an integer?

The error comes from `django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py`.

The query variable in the locals for that stack frame:

```
'INSERT INTO "MODEL" ("A", "provenance", "B", "C") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING "MODEL"."id"'
args
(False,
 0,
 u'test',
 '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6',
 )
```

Which suggests that the query building receives the correct parameter (0). NB the '%s' are not standard format placeholders, for Django query-building `%s` is the only type.

So it all looks correct.

What's going on?

Comment: I have implemented the model in `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` and I was able to save `ModelForm` without any errors :O

Comment: Yes, the form has worked before. Something has changed, somewhere, and I'm trying to diagnose what. I have re-installed the lastest Django 1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tracked it down. Like the best trackings-down, a bit of a story.

First I put a breakpoint in `backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py` in `CursorWrapper.execute` and ascertained that it was not possible to step into with `pdb`, so it must be a C module.

So I searched for the exact error "is not of a character type", which led me to the source PostgreSQL code for the `tsvector`, which is used in full-text search. The line:

```
01419         if (!is_text_type(SPI_gettypeid(rel->rd_att, numattr)))
01420             ereport(ERROR,
01421                     (errcode(ERRCODE_DATATYPE_MISMATCH),
01422                      errmsg("column \"%s\" is not of a character type",
01423               trigger->tgargs[i])));
```

Found in http://doxygen.postgresql.org/tsvector__op_8c_source.html

So it's trying to create a tsvector out of the field in question.

So I looked at the schema, and lo and behold I have a trigger.

```
Triggers:
MY_TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MY_TABLE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('text_index', 'pg_catalog.english', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'provenance')
```

I had forgotten about this. I don't know why it worked before, and then stopped working, but that was the problem.

**tl;dr
An update trigger was building a `tsvector` out of the field, and was complaining about the type. There was nothing wrong with the data, or the driver, just the trigger execting the wrong type of data.**

Comment: Holy flying crap with lasers! This is exactly the problem I'm facing! Thanks man! :D